# Finding an element using "find_element_by_xpath"

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find an element using "find_element_by_xpath" but getting error which says "Unable to locate element".

I have also tried giving implicit wait but still not able to locate the element.

The HTML file looks like:

```
<div class="actions">
<input type="submit" value="Save" data-action="save">
</div> 
<input type="hidden" name=actionId>
```

I had tried below line of code:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//class[@name='
actions']/input[@type='submit']"

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='form- 
submit']/input[@type='submit']")
```

All the above tries show the error "No such element: Unable to locate element"

I had tried "execute_script" for handling hidden element,

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

This is not giving any error but I am not sure if it is clicking on the correct button as a new webpage is opening with a message "The page you are trying could not be reached".

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath seems to be fine, please check if the element is located inside an iframe and if yes, then first switch to the iframe and then you can operate on the element.

To switch to the iframe you can use: `driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))` and then you can operate on the element and for switching back to the default content, you can use `driver.switch_to_default_content()`

Comment: There is no iframe in the html, but I have observed there were <input type = "hidden"> present just outside this class, I have tried "execute_script" (I have also modified the question) but found a new issue.

Comment: So, have you tried clicking the element manually ? Which page does it open when you click on it manually ?

Comment: Yes I am able to click on the button manually and after that it remains on the same page, with a notification that the page is saved.